# Trigger is not working properly

Tags: apex, trigger

i have created the below trigger which will help in updating the opportunity amount if there is any change in the amount of the child record platform__c but i want to put the sum of closed won platform amount in the opportunity amount otherwise will show sum of all child record.

```
trigger amountupdate1 on platform__c (after update, after insert, after delete) {
    opportunity ops = new opportunity ();
    list <opportunity> o = new list <opportunity>();
    double amount=0;
    double Camount;
    if (trigger.isdelete){
        for (platform__c plt2: Trigger.old){
            amount=plt2.amount__C;
            ops= [select ID,name,amount from opportunity where ID =: plt2.Opportunity__c];
            ops.amount=ops.amount-amount;
            update (ops);
        }
    }
    else {
        For (platform__c plt: Trigger.new){
            Amount = 0;
            CAmount=0;
            for (platform__c plt1: [select ID, amount__c, stage__c from platform__C where platform__c.Opportunity__c =: plt.opportunity__c]){
                if (plt1.stage__c=='Closed Won'){
                    CAmount= plt1.amount__c + CAmount;
                }else {
                    Amount= plt1.amount__c + Amount;
                }
            }
            ops= [select ID,name from opportunity where ID =: plt.Opportunity__c];
            if (camount>0){
                ops.amount=camount;
            }else {
                ops.amount=amount;
            }
            update (ops);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should create a rollup summary field if it is master detail, or use [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) if not.

Comment: cant we do this using the trigger it would be great if you let me know where i am doing wrong ? because currently it is taking sum of all child record amount.

Comment: If you are struggling with the `Apex`, you should use the tools at hand and not make this functionality more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: You have SOQL queries inside of a for loop. This is not bulkified and will blow up if you try to run 200 records through it; throwing an exception at 101 queries. You'll also exceed DML limits as well when it hits 150 records. This approach isn't going to work for you.

Comment: One of the salesforce pdfs I read had a really great sentence in there: *A code that you don't write is the code you don't have to maintain*. As Adrian Larson said in his comment, use Rollup summary field or a dlrs. You should really not write any code for something that can be done with just point-and-click tools

Answer (score 1):

You should be simply doing a Rollup Summary field on the Opportunity as this looks like it could be a MD to opportunity...The trigger is overkill in this case but just for kicks

Here is something I quickly mocked up to give you an example without the SOQL in Loops. IIRC it could be easier with Group By Rollup or Cube but did not have time to think that one out

```
trigger amountupdate1 on platform__c (after update, after insert, after delete) {

    Set<ID> oppIds = New Set<ID>();
    Opportunity[] oppsToUpdate = New Opportunity[]{};
    platform__c[] records = trigger.isDelete ? trigger.old : trigger.new;

    //Get IDs for Opps
    for(platform__c p : records)
        oppids.add(p.Opportunity__c);

    //Aggregate Result grouped by Opp and Stage
    Aggregate[] arList = [Select Opportunity__c, Stage__c, sum(amount__c)total From platform__c Where Opportunity__c in :oppIds Group By Opportunity__c, Stage__c];

    Id currentOpp;
    Dcimal closedTotal = 0;
    Decimal allTotal = 0;

    //Loop thru results
    for(AggregateResult ar : arList){
        //If first one or the opp changes
        if((Id)ar.get('Opportunity__c') != currentOpp){
            if(currentOpp == null){ //First one so just set current opp
                currentOpp = (ID)ar.get('Opportunity__c');
            }else{ //On the next Opp so populate record for update
                oppsToUpdate.add(
                    New Opportunity(id = currentOpp, Amount = closedTotal == 0 ? allTotal : closedTotal)
                );

                currentOpp = (ID)ar.get('Opportunity__c');
                closedTotal = 0; //reset values
                allTotal = 0;
            }
        }

        //Add the close amounts to the variable
        if((String)ar.get('Stage__c') == 'Closed Won')
            closedTotal += (Decimal)ar.get(total);

        //Add amount to all total variable
        allTotal += (Decimal)ar.get(total);
    }

    //Capture the last one
    if(!ar.isempty()){
        oppsToUpdate.add(
            New Opportunity(id = (id)ar.get('Opportunity__c'), Amount = closedTotal == 0 ? allTotal : closedTotal)
        );      
    }

    update oppsToUpdate;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get this line outside the for loop:

ops= [select ID,name from opportunity where ID =: plt.Opportunity__c];
thank you Make sure all soql is outside any loops.
thank you